# Exec ping command doesn't work on Linux Centos

Tags: php, linux, centos, exec, ping

Good day,

I am working on a system which checks whether a certain IP address is up or down. I have a MySQL DB with a table containing a list of IP addresses.I have created the following function to ping the IP address:

```
function pingAddress($ip) {

        $result = exec('ping $ip -i 15 ', $outcome, $status);

        if (0 == $status) {
            echo 'Server UP ';
        } else {
            echo 'Server down ';
        }
}
```

and in my while loop I have the following:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
   ?>
   <tr>
       <td><?php pingAddress($row['client_ip_address']); ?></td>
   </tr>

   <?php
   } //end while
  ?>
```

However instead of getting 0 (because servers are up) I always get 2.

I have replaced the line `$result = exec('ping $ip -i 15 ', $outcome, $status);`
with `$pingresult = system("ping -n 3 $ip 2>&1", $outcome, $status);`
OR `$pingresult = shell_exec('/bin/ping -qc 1 '.$ip.' | awk -F/ \'/^rtt/\'', $result); OR ('ping $ip -i 15 ', $outcome, $status);`
Still the result didn't change. Either I got an empty array (when I do `var_dump($status)` or `var_dump($outcome)`).

I am using Centos7 with apache installed on it.

I am a missing something because I have tried virtually the majority of solutions suggested here based on previous similar questions but it didn't work.

Is there a much better way code such a system?

Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 2):

You likely need to modify the syntax of `exec`:

```
$result = exec('ping -i 15 -c 3 ' . $ip, $outcome, $status);
```

Also, you might include `-c` or whatever your ping `count` option is... otherwise it will run forever.

Comment: Hi. Using $result = exec('ping -i 15 -c 3 '. $ip, $outcome, $status) and doing a var_dump($status) gave me a result of int(2). When I change the . to , before the $ip var and do a var_dump($status) I go a NULL result. I also tried $result = exec("ping -i 15 -c 3 2>&1". $ip, $outcome, $status); but the result of var_dump($status) was int(2).

Comment: It might help to know what you are trying to ping; maybe as a test try 'google.com' for $ip ( try just the first block of code ). If it works then you can figure it's likely the mysql not being correct.

Comment: I have a list of local IP addresses (e.g 192.168.100.110). From windows cmd or my server terminal I can ping those IP addresses successfully (because my web server has an IP address in the same network). For testing purposes I am pinging google dns 8.8.8.8 but the result is the same.